# Would this be sequential access or random access?

Tags: hard-drive

Random read is when you read random 4KB or so files from the HDD. Sequential is when you read a large file, 128KB or so.

Now, if I have a big file, say 1GB, read 10 bytes at the start, seek a few MBs, read another 10 bytes and goes on, but **never seek back**, what kind of performance can I expect and what is this called?

Comment: I don't know about this with hard drives, but random and sequential are two access methods, methods for reading and maybe writing. Sequential if it wants to read line 5 it has to read lines 1-4 first etc. Random it can read whatever line you ask it to without reading the ones before it. And I recall VB you could open a file as random or as sequential access. With hard drives i'm not sure but  I suppose if you want to read a file you may as well read it sequentially. If it's a small file maybe there's some benefit in reading ramdon parts of it and putting them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Random read is when you start anywhere you like in the file and read as much as you like, jumping back and forth as you like. Sequential read is when you start at the beginning of the file and read as much as you like from there on, but never skip anything or move back.

Using the `seek` command to move to a different part of the file means that you are using random read. If you would use sequential read you would have to read all the data in the file up to the point where the relevant data was, which would of course be slow. As you can go directly to the right position in the file means that there is not much overhead and you can expect good performance.

Comment: Yes, but I never seek back, isn't this an advantage?

Comment: @Luka: No, when you are skipping forward as much as a few MB you can't make it more efficient that using random read. If you would never skip more than a few kB, then you could use sequential read instead, and take advantage of the read-ahead of the disk.